# Google Cloud Vision text detection issues with text language management

Tags: google-cloud-vision

I've encountered the following issues with the text detection feature of Google Cloud Vision:

1) I submit the same image using the same Python code to Google Cloud Vision, from 2 different machines (the Windows-based development machine and the Linux-based "production" machine) but I get 2 different outputs. Same image, same code, same libraries, but the extracted text is different.

2) I get two differently detected locales for the two differently detected texts. My original text is Italian text mixed with digits. On the development machine, the detected locale is "zh" (Chinese). On the "production" machine, the detected locale is "fil". There isn't any "fil" code in https://cloud.google.com/translate/v2/using_rest#language-params so I don't know what it is (Filipino?). In any case, I get a better result on the development machine when the detected locale is "zh". So... same image, same code, but differently detected locale and differently detected text.

3) Therefore I try to force the "it" or "zh" locale using the ImageContext languageHints annotation https://cloud.google.com/vision/reference/rest/v1/images/annotate#AnnotateImageRequest and now there's the funny thing: if I set languageHints to ['it'] on the development machine, I get almost nothing as output from Google Cloud Vision. If I set it to ['ja'] (Japanese), Google Cloud Vision says that the text locale is "it" (!!) and I get some decent results (!!!). But if I set ['ja'] on the "production" machine, Google Cloud Vision says that the text locale is "oc" (?). So... same image, same code, but differently detected locale and differently detected text. Moreover, the detected locale and text don't follow what I set with languageHints, but when I change the languageHints parameter, the detected locale (and text) also changes in an unpredictable way.

Do you have any hint? Thanks.